# How to move table column down when a cell spans to n columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My HMTL layout is displayed as a table with table-row and table-cell. If I want to expand a particular cell such that it spans to 2 columns, the neighboring cell should move down as the space is already occupied by the one that expands.

In the below example, I want to make Row 1 Column 1 to occupy two columns. So Row 1 Column 2 should move 1 row down. Is this possible in HTML/CSS?

**Normal Layout:**
[image]

**Expected Result:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <div class="table-custom">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell" colspan="2">
        <div>Row 1 Column 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <div>Row 1 Column 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <div>Row 1 Column 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <div>Row 2 Column 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <div>Row 2 Column 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        <div>Row 2 Column 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vg0L7m2y/

Comment: dont you want to use tables?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `<table>` and use `colspan` with `cellspacing` to achieve your desired result?

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/q3vpc84m/)